# Scene2d ScrollPane not scrolling

Tags: java, layout, libgdx, scene2d

I create a ScrollPane, with table inside. It works fine, but when I add this ScrollPane to layout Table (or VecrticalGroup) it stops working.

```
    layoutTable = new Table();
    groupTable = new Table();
    SP = new ScrollPane(groupTable, skin);
    SP.setWidth(1105);
    SP.setHeight(300);
    groupTable.top();
    groupTable.left();

    layoutTable.add(inputTable);
    layoutTable.row();
    layoutTable.add(SP);
    layoutTable.row();
    layoutTable.add(resultTable);
    layoutTable.setFillParent(true);
    stage.addActor(layoutTable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you add it to the table, the table manages its size, so your earlier calls (`SP.setWidth()` and `SP.setHeight()`) are overwritten (probably with whatever is the prefSize of the scroll pane's contents, which is zero if it's an empty table). If you want to control the scroll pane's size, do it by adjusting its cell when you add it to the table:

```
layoutTable.add(SP).width(1105).height(300).fill();
```

The `fill()` call tells the table to resize the scroll pane to fit the cell dimensions.